# Filter a list of Hash map with filter conditions given in another Hash map Java

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream

Let us assume I have a list of Object P.

```
Class P {
    int id;
    Map<String,String> value;
}
```

A value looks like

```
value = {
    "Category" : "Category 1",
    "family" : "Family 1",
    "color" : "Color 1"
}
```

As mentioned above, I have list of P. Let assume that list is listP.

```
map1 = {
    "Category" : "Category 1",
    "family" : "Family 1",
    "color" : "Color 1"
}
map2 = {
    "Category" : "Category 2",
    "family" : "Family 2",
    "color" : "Color 1"
}
map3 = {
    "Category" : "Category 1",
    "family" : "Family 1",
    "color" : "Color 2"
}
map4 = {
    "Category" : "Category 2",
    "family" : "Family 1",
    "color" : "Color 1"
}
List<P> listP = [
    P(1, map1),
    P(2, map2),
    P(3, map3),
    P(4, map4),
]
```

I want to filter on various conditions. The conditions is in form of map.

```
filter = {
   "color" : "Color 1",
   "family" : "Family 1"
}
```

After filtering, as evident, the output will be

```
List<P> listP = [
    P(1, map1),
    P(4, map4),
]
```

**map1** and **map4** refers to maps as defined in *code snippet* above.
Long story short, I want alternative of Python code mentioned below (it's not for these classes but idea is same.

```
filterC = {
    "color" : "Color 1",
    "family" : "Family 1"
}

inputL = [
    {
        "Category" : "Category 1",
        "family" : "Family 1",
        "color" : "Color 1"
    },
    {
        "Category" : "Category 1",
        "family" : "Family 1",
        "color" : "Color 2"
    },
    {
        "Category" : "Category 1",
        "family" : "Family 2",
        "color" : "Color 1"
    },
    {
        "Category" : "Category 2",
        "family" : "Family 1",
        "color" : "Color 1"
    },
]

outputL = [inp for inp in inputL if all(inp[k] == v for k,v in filterC.items())]
```

As suggested in comment, I have added my code and sample value for **value** attribute of class Product (referred as P above)

```
Map<String, String> filter = new HashMap<String, String>();
        filter.put("Category","7018");
        filter.put("Carbon","0.075");

        List<Product> productList= productRepository.findAll();


        List<Product> prodList = productList.stream()
                .filter(prod -> filter.entrySet().stream().allMatch(e -> prod.getValue().get(e.getKey()) == e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sample

```
{Category=7018, Hydrogen=5, Moisture=0.3, Product Name=New Product, Ferrite (Fn)=, Vanadium=0.025, Phosphorus=0.0175, Hardness=, Carbon=0.075, Molybdenum=0.1, UTS=550, Columbium=, Chromium=0.1, YS=200, Nickel=0.15, Silicon=0.375, Hardness_Scale=HRC, Sulfur=0.0175, Copper=, Elongation=11, Manganese=0.8}
```

I am able to do the task using normal loops and basic lambda but I am unable to utilize filter and collect. Any help in the direction will be appreciated. I have followed few tutorials, but I am new to Java when it comes to functional programming. Thanks, in advance.

Edit - Converted id in P to int from String to avoid confusion. No relation to doubt but just for clarity

Comment: Would be helpful to all if you would put in the actual maps and not Json.

Comment: Thanks, WJS for inputs. I have added the code. My thought was that it might confuse anyone, so I was avoiding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have input data as below

```
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(first, second, ..);
```

And your filter map is

```
Map<String, String> filters = new HashMap<>();

filters.put("color", "xyz");
```

then you can filter using this.

```
List<Product> data = products
  .stream()
  .filter(element -> filter.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .allMatch(criteria -> Objects.equals(criteria.getValue(), 
                            element.getValue().get(criteria.getKey()))))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hey, @lucid, I have attached my code which I was trying. Can you point out the mistake there? My code is not throwing any error. It just filters empty data. But, as mentioned in sample itself, there is atleast one product satisfying the filter criteria. And there are many.

Comment: @Plasmatiger problem is with `allMatch(e -> prod.getValue().get(e.getKey()) == e.getValue())` part, it will match reference.  you can replace with this `Objects.equal(prod.getValue().get(e.getKey()), e.getValue())`

Comment: thanks a lot. I feel very silly. The basic mistake of Java while string matching. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Saved the day.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

The following will do what you want to achieve

```
List<Product> filteredProducts = products.stream()
            .filter(product -> filter.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .allMatch(e -> product.getValue().get(e.getKey()) != null && product.getValue().get(e.getKey()).equals(e.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically iterate over all elements in the list and filter for all the key/values in the filter map. Or a better way would be

```
List<Product> filteredProducts = products.stream()
            .filter(product ->  product.getValue().entrySet().containsAll(filter.entrySet()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where filter is like

```
Map<String, String> filter = new HashMap<>();
    filter.put("color", "Color 1");
    filter.put("family", "Family 1");
```

Comment: Hey, @harsh, I have attached my code which I was trying. Can you point out the mistake there? My code is not throwing any error. It just filters empty data. But, as mentioned in sample itself, there is atleast one product satisfying the filter criteria. And there are many

Comment: @Plasmatiger it is `==` (checks for reference equivalence) vs `equals` (checks for content equivalence in case of String), but it'd be better to use `filter(product ->  product.value.entrySet().containsAll(filter.entrySet()))` which is a cleaner solution

Comment: Yeah, @lucid pointed that out. feeling silly. I was looking at mistake in predicate while it was object equality. Thanks, for commenting. Saved my day.